# XFBML Facebook Like button - customising the add comment text input

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

By default, after a user clicks on 'Like' they are given the option to add a comment to their Like.

Since my Like button is wrapped in a div with fixed height, the resulting comment text input is cut off and looks ugly. Is there any known way to:

- disable this default behaviour using the JS API (I am using the latest one)?
- target the css of the comment text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my Like button is wrapped in a div with fixed height, the resulting comment text input is cut off and looks ugly. Is there any known way to:

- disable this default behaviour using the JS API (I am using the latest one)?
- target the css of the comment text field?

No, there is no way to disable that behaviour of the plugin.

Not really, it is not advised to play with the css of the plugin.

Now to solve the original problem.  I have a fixed height div that my like plugin resides in and the popup works splendidly.  Here's what I did to make it work.

```
<div style="height: 20px; z-index: 10001;"> <!-- this is my fixed height div -->
  <div style="position: relative; width: 100px; z-index: 10002;" >
    <div data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-width="100" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change this behavior or style this component using CSS. But you can use `iframe` version of Like Button social widget which doesn't have ability to add comments, you should be aware that `iframe` version will not trigger `edge.create` and `edge.remove` events.